# amfe-flexible and postCSS not working with echarts

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to use amfe-flexible and postCSS together with echarts, but I am facing an issue where echarts is not functioning as expected. Despite integrating amfe-flexible and postCSS into my project, echarts charts and visualizations are not being displayed correctly or not showing up at all.

I have ensured that I have included the necessary echarts JavaScript file and followed the documentation provided by echarts for proper usage. I have also checked for any errors or warnings in the browser's console, but there are no relevant messages related to echarts or the integration with amfe-flexible and postCSS.

I have verified that the versions of amfe-flexible, postCSS, and echarts are compatible and there are no conflicts between them. I have also tried removing the configurations of amfe-flexible and postCSS temporarily to see if that resolves the issue, but the problem still persists.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue and make amfe-flexible, postCSS, and echarts work together seamlessly.